# git am from branch to master

Tags: git, version-control

I'm working together with a college of mine in git.
I'm working on a branch, and he's working on the master.
I've done some work related to his files on my branch, and I decided to send him a patch file.
I created the patch with `git format-patch`, and sent it to him.
when he tries to apply the patch using `git am` he get's the following message: `previous release directory`

It's probably because the patch arrived from a different branch.

Is there a way for him to use the patch on the master branch ?

Note: I'm using `git am`, and not `git apply` to keep commit-id that is generated for jetty.
I still want the commiter to be me on his local repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using one of the two solutions when dealing with [patches that fails to apply properly](http://www.pizzhacks.com/bugdrome/2011/10/deal-with-git-am-failures/):
(article from [bugdromer](http://www.pizzhacks.com/bugdrome/author/bugdromer/)):

---

> The simplest way for dealing with it would be to:
>
> - `git am --abort`,
> - apply the patch manually by `patch -p1 < PATCH`,
> - resolve the conflict by hand,
> - and finally commit with `git commit -a`.
>
> But in this case you'll have to rewrite the commit message, which is not very nice. There is a more clever way.

---

> You can find the corresponding patch file stored in `.git/rebase-apply`, and named "`0001`" (the name of the dir where the patch is stored changed recently, this is tested with 1.7.4.1).
>   At this point:
>
> - **you can use `git apply` for applying the patch, which is the git equivalent of the patch command**,
> - and fix the conflicting files the usual way (you check the `.rej` files, compare them with the conflicting files and finally add the fixed files to the index):
>
> Example:

```
$ git apply PATCH --reject
$ edit edit edit
$ git add FIXED_FILES
$ git am --resolved
```

> and you're done!
>   In other words, since `git am` didn't change the index, you need to
>
> - **`git apply --reject`** the patch (stored in `.git/rebase-apply`),
> - fix conflicts by hand,
> - add the changed files and
> - finally tell git that you resolved the trouble.
>
> The advantage in this case is that:
>
> - you don't need to re-edit the commit message,
> - and in the case you're applying a set of patches (that is you're using `git am PATCHES`, where `PATCHES` is a mailbox), you don't have to `git abort` and `run git am` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `--3way` option of `git am`:

> ```
> -3, --3way
>    When the patch does not apply cleanly, fall back on 3-way merge if
>    the patch records the identity of blobs it is supposed to apply to
>    and we have those blobs available locally.
> ```